# Idiomatic else if chain for a map key

Tags: go

I have a fairly long else if chain looking for keys in a map and setting a specific value if found. The way I chose to do it with the least amount of code was this (`m` is a `map[string]interface{}`)

```
var ok bool
var s interface{}
if s, ok = m["key1"]; ok {
} else if s, ok = m["key2"]; ok {
           ....
} else if s, ok = m["keyN"]; ok {
} else {
   return RuhRohError
}
g.Id = s.(string)
```

This feels kinda clunky, I am doing all of these `else if`'s to set a variable in the condition. Is there an idiomatic way to do this? I think this way doesn't make it immediately obvious what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func findValue(m map[string]interface{}, keys []string) (interface{}, bool) {
    for _, key := range keys {
        if value, ok := m[key]; ok {
            return value, true
        }
    }
    return nil, false
}

func main() {
    m := map[string]interface{}{"keyn": "valuen"}
    keys := []string{"key1", "key2", "keyn"}
    s, found := findValue(m, keys)
    if !found {
        return
    }
    id := s.(string)
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

Output:

```
valuen
```

Comment: I was thinking of this exact solution as well. Seems a bit more readable. Could also make `findValue(m map[string]interface{}, keys ...string)`

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think the code you provided is very easy to read and understand. It is a bit verbose but there is no magic ;). So if there is only one place where you have to write this code I would leave it as it is. If you need to write it a few times I would consider writing `findValue` function mentioned in another comment.

Comment: That is why I didn't write the findValue function. Also I believe using `:=` would not work as the variable is only scoped to the if statement when you do that